# "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification" after update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I work on a former app that I must update
I get following message in build.gradle :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

I have found this post :
[All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

But I still get the message :
[image]

And if I add reference to 26 version :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: this question had been asked and answered over and over. didn't you notice the `play-services` yet?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sorry, all the post I found (like the one I mention) don't talk about play-services....My question is clear and I have done research... So why negative vote !! Sorry not to be an expert !

Comment: that wasn't me. and that `12.0.1` version still could be removed.